# Copiar Strings em C

Tags: c, string

Tenho a seguinte matriz bidimensional de strings. 
`char matriz[linhas][tamanhoDaString]`
Através do `strcpy` copiei uma string para lá.

```
char *aux = "abc";
strcpy(matriz, aux);
```

O meu objectivo era colocar na `linha 3` a string `aux`.

Como é que consigo resolver o meu problema?

Comment: Tente: strcpy(matriz[2], aux); (considerando que o índice parte de 0 e portanto a terceira linha seja matriz[2]).

Comment: Veja teste em: http://ideone.com/Gk6tdH

Comment: @Urbester: sugiro que ligues os warnings do teu compilador.

Comment: Eu tenho os warnings ligados, estou a compilar directamente na consola linux. Já consegui resolver o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta colocar o índice, pois assim você especifica a que posição de seu array 2D você deseja copiar o valor:

```
strcpy(matriz[2], aux);
```

Answer (score 5):

`matriz` não é uma string: é um array de strings.
Não podes usar `matriz` directamente nas funções `str*`; tens que usar os seus elementos.

O terceiro elemento de `matriz` é `matriz[2]`, esse elemento é (*ou melhor, pode ser*) uma string.

```
const char *aux = "abc"; // eu gosto de por o const para o compilador me
                         // avisar se eu tentar alterar o conteúdo de aux
if (strlen(aux) >= sizeof *matriz) {
    // o tamanho de cada elemento de matriz
    // nao é suficiente para o comprimento de aux
} else {
    strcpy(matriz[2], aux);
}
```

Comment: Não esqueça de levar em conta o terminador nulo! Use `stdlen(aux)+1`.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal: obrigado pela chamada de atenção; o `>=` já toma conta do terminador.