# Ao imprimir string, são mostrados caracteres sem sentido

Tags: c, array, c++, string

Eu preciso fazer um programa que calcule a média de salários de uma empresa, pedindo ao usuário a quantidade de funcionários, o nome e o salário de cada funcionário e devolvendo a média, o nome do funcionário com salário mais alto e o nome do funcionário com salário mais baixo.

Sendo que o programa deve solicitar antes de tudo a quantidade de funcionários para depois pedir os nomes de cada um deles.

O programa já está quase pronto, o único problema é que na hora da execução ele não mostra os nomes como deveria mostrar, mas sim um monte de caracteres sem sentido. Alguém pode me dizer onde está meu erro?

```
char nome[11], nome_maior[11], nome_menor[11];
int quant, cont = 1;
float salario, salario_maior = 0, salario_menor=999999, media, soma;

printf("Digite a quantidade de funcionários: "); scanf("%d", &quant);

while(cont <= quant){
    printf("\nInsira o NOME do funcionário: "); scanf("%s", nome);
    printf("\nInsira o salário: "); scanf("%f", &salario);
    soma = soma + salario;
    cont = cont + 1;
    if(salario < salario_menor){
       nome_menor == nome;  
       salario_menor = salario;
    }if(salario > salario_maior){
        nome_maior == nome;
        salario_maior = salario;
    }}
            printf("\nO maior salário é de %s com %.2f", nome_maior, salario_maior);
            printf("\nO menor salário é de %s com %.2f", nome_menor, salario_menor);
            printf("\nA média dos salários apresentados é de %.2f", media=salario/quant);
return 0;
```

[image: Caracteres estranhos]

Comment: `if(salario < salario_menor){ nome_menor == nome; ` Isto não faz o que pretende por varios motivos. Primeiramente é `==` de comparação e não `=` de atribuição e segundo atribuição de strings em C é feito com `strcpy`. Relacionadas ou duplicatas [Copiar Strings em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10235/copiar-strings-em-c), [Qual a diferença entre atribuir e comparar variáveis strings com função ou com operador de atribuição e comparação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80074/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-atribuir-e-comparar-vari%C3%A1veis-strings-com-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ou-com-o)

Comment: Ainda entrei no conteúdo de strcpy, o máximo que vimos sobre string foi o básico do básico, nem entramos na biblioteca de strings, mas se a questão pede isso vou dar uma procurada em como usar. Obrigado!